# Split xml dynamically on the fly using StAX in Java, alternatives?

Tags: java, xml, inputstream, stax

Because processing big xml files in a limited (RAM) environment can be an issue especially using java AND forced to use Jsoup as parser, I decided to do "on the fly processing" using SAX and also StAX: After several attempts I end up with my code that so far I couldn't find on internet, because it's very general.

The idea is simple, you have a inputStream already decompressed on the fly, that contains a XML file, and you need to split or (chunk) one specific object inside this xml file with all it's inner XML code and give this string to some other parser (like Jsoup).

Of course my first attempt was to use the Jsoup native inputStream reader, but it actually downloads the complete XML file and then parses it, using a big amount of RAM.

So my code looks like this, and my unit tests works perfect and everything seams to me Ok, **BUT the issue is that, some times, with some XMLs in other servers it only extract the (ODD) objects**, so the 1st then 3th and so on but not the (EVEN) ones.

```
public int xmlStreamProcess(HandlerAPI productHandler, ...//some instructions) throws CupoHttpException {
    int total = 0;
    String element = ... // CSS selector for the element to take
    String[] parameters = ... // instructions what to do with that element
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        XMLStreamReader streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(retrieveFileStream());
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration","yes"); // I tried this options didn't have difference 
        t.setOutputProperty("standalone","no"); // nothing changed

        while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
            int eventType = streamReader.next();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                    String elementName = streamReader.getLocalName();
                    if (element.equals(elementName)) {
                        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
                        t.transform(new StAXSource(streamReader), result); // this is the only point where I loose information
                        String strResult = writer.toString(); // and here is the piece of XML ready to parse.
                        if (productHandler.apiHandle(Parser.map2Object(Parser.parseElement(Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(strResult), parameters))
                        )) {
                            total++;
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
            streamReader.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CupoHttpException("Error in stream process", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Sadly I can't provide the real working xml examples, but as you can see it should work for any of them.

Example: Input = selector "A_object"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
<one_level>
<A_object id=1>
<content_of_a>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</content_of_a>
</A_object>
<A_object id=2>
<content_of_a>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</content_of_a>
</A_object>
<A_object id=3>
<content_of_a>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</content_of_a>
</A_object>
<A_object id=4>
<content_of_a>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</content_of_a>
</A_object>
<A_object id=5>
<content_of_a>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</content_of_a>
</A_object>
</one_level>
</example>
```

Example: output

first:

```
<A_object id=1>
<content_of_a>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</content_of_a>
</A_object>
```

second:

```
<A_object id=2>
<content_of_a>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</stuff>
</content_of_a>
</A_object>
```

...
..
.
Is there any other way to do something similar?

Comment: "Sometimes": which times? Do you really expect strangers on the Internet to debug your code for you when you provide them with less information than you have?

Comment: I'm sorry Raedwald, this is more a "is there another way todo it?" than a tell me where is the error in my code.
As I said, the code has it's unit test and it's all ok, but the unit tests I do with xmls in servers I control, but when a xml from other server comes I can't be sure that this will work, and there is nothing wrong with the code.
for what I know there shouldn't be difference, but there is, and this is the question here.
sorry for disturbing.